Initializing Token2022 Metadata with PDA mint authority
I've read through a lot of similar questions but I'm quite stumped here.
I'm creating a mint PDA like so:
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[event_cpi]
pub struct Init<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = admin,
        space = ANCHOR_DISCRIMINATOR + Info::INIT_SPACE,
        seeds = [b"info"],
        bump
    )]
    pub info: Account<'info, Info>,

    // Create mint account
    // Same PDA as address of the account and mint/freeze authority
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = admin,
        seeds = [b"mint"],
        mint::decimals = 9,
        mint::authority = mint_account.key(),
        mint::freeze_authority = mint_account.key(),
        extensions::metadata_pointer::authority = admin,
        extensions::metadata_pointer::metadata_address = mint_account,
        bump,
    )]
    pub mint_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token2022>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

In my init function I am then doing this:
// Define token metadata
    let token_metadata = TokenMetadata {
        name: "TOKEN".to_string(),
        symbol: "TOKEN".to_string(),
        uri: "https:/placeholder.uri".to_string(),
        ..Default::default()
    };

    // Add 4 extra bytes for size of MetadataExtension (2 bytes for type, 2 bytes for length)
    let data_len = 4 + token_metadata.get_packed_len()?;

    // Calculate lamports required for the additional metadata
    let lamports =
        data_len as u64 * DEFAULT_LAMPORTS_PER_BYTE_YEAR * DEFAULT_EXEMPTION_THRESHOLD as u64;

    // Transfer additional lamports to mint account
    transfer(
        CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            Transfer {
                from: ctx.accounts.admin.to_account_info(),
                to: ctx.accounts.mint_account.to_account_info(),
            },
        ),
        lamports,
    )?;

    // Initialize token metadata
    token_metadata_initialize(
        CpiContext::new_with_signer(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            TokenMetadataInitialize {
                token_program_id: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                metadata: ctx.accounts.mint_account.to_account_info(),
                update_authority: ctx.accounts.admin.to_account_info(),
                mint: ctx.accounts.mint_account.to_account_info(),
                mint_authority: ctx.accounts.admin.to_account_info(),
            },
            &[&[
            b"mint", 
            &[ctx.bumps.mint_account],
        ]]
        ),
        "TOKEN".to_string(),
        "TOKEN".to_string(),
        "https:/placeholder.uri".to_string(),
    )?;

If I comment out the token_metadata_initialize my tests pass, but with it in I get this error:
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x35c2b5bf. 
Logs: 
[
  "Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb success",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success",
  "Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb invoke [2]",
  "Program log: TokenMetadataInstruction: Initialize",
  "Program log: Error: Unknown",
  "Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb consumed 2490 of 168532 compute units",
  "Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb failed: custom program error: 0x35c2b5bf",
  "Program 2tvCpDDBEkmsdrk1qYfqixbBQ49d4CqLK4tiC4oQq9Cw consumed 33958 of 200000 compute units",
  "Program 2tvCpDDBEkmsdrk1qYfqixbBQ49d4CqLK4tiC4oQq9Cw failed: custom program error: 0x35c2b5bf"
]. 

Any ideas?

The error log is a bit unclear in this case unfortunately:
  "Program log: Error: Unknown",

This is typically an error from Borsh deserialization, so there's something up with the serialized data passed to the program.
What's shocking though, is that the first log of TokenMetadataInstruction: Initialize is being output, so the instruction data is correctly formatted.
The only thing I can see is that the incorrect mint authority is being passed in, but that would normally trigger another error. Either way, can you try changing:
            TokenMetadataInitialize {
                token_program_id: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                metadata: ctx.accounts.mint_account.to_account_info(),
                update_authority: ctx.accounts.admin.to_account_info(),
                mint: ctx.accounts.mint_account.to_account_info(),
                mint_authority: ctx.accounts.mint_account.to_account_info(),
            },


Yes it ended up being the incorrect mint authority, thank you so much :)
